# Can't do cycle in WebDriver while element is invisible

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I need to do some things when element is invisible:

```
public boolean checkGameOver(){
    return(driver.findElement(gameOverMessage).isDisplayed());
}

while (!checkGameOver()) {
    page.pushRandomKey(keys);
}
```

It throws exception: Unable to locate element, because element gameOverMessage is invisible.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
public int checkGameOver(){
        return(driver.findElements(gameOverMessage).size());
    }
while (page.checkGameOver()==0) {
                page.pushRandomKey(keys);

            }
```